# Running a task after all tasks have been completed

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm writing an application which needs to run a series of tasks in parallel and then a single task with the results of all the tasks run:

```
@celery.task
def power(value, expo):
    return value ** expo

@celery.task
def amass(values):
    print str(values)
```

It's a very contrived and oversimplified example, but hopefully the point comes across well. Basically, I have *many* items which need to run through `power`, but I only want to run `amass` on the results from all of the tasks. All of this should happen asynchronously, and I don't need anything back from the `amass` method.

Does anyone know how to set this up in celery so that everything is executed asynchronously and a single callback with a list of the results is called after all is said and done?

I've setup this example to run with a `chord` as Alexander Afanasiev recommended:

```
from time import sleep

import random

tasks = []

for i in xrange(10):
    tasks.append(power.s((i, 2)))
    sleep(random.randint(10, 1000) / 1000.0) # sleep for 10-1000ms

callback = amass.s()

r = chord(tasks)(callback)
```

Unfortunately, in the above example, all tasks in `tasks` are started only when the `chord` method is called. Is there a way that each task can start separately and then I could add a callback to the group to run when everything has finished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution which worked for my purposes:

**tasks.py**:

```
from time import sleep

import random

@celery.task
def power(value, expo):
    sleep(random.randint(10, 1000) / 1000.0) # sleep for 10-1000ms
    return value ** expo

@celery.task
def amass(results, tasks):
    completed_tasks = []
    for task in tasks:
        if task.ready():
            completed_tasks.append(task)
            results.append(task.get())

    # remove completed tasks
    tasks = list(set(tasks) - set(completed_tasks))

    if len(tasks) > 0:
        # resend the task to execute at least 1 second from now
        amass.delay(results, tasks, countdown=1)
    else:
        # we done
        print results
```

**Use Case:**

```
tasks = []

for i in xrange(10):
    tasks.append(power.delay(i, 2))

amass.delay([], tasks)
```

What this *should* do is start all of the tasks as soon as possible asynchronously. Once they've all been posted to the queue, the `amass` task will also be posted to the queue. The amass task will keep reposting itself until all of the other tasks have been completed.

Comment: Hi, looks like the above is a good approach, at least conceptually. However, when I tried it out, the exact same code as above, it throws the below error:
`EncodeError: <AsyncResult: cf5875f1-7f72-449c-9808-07c9c9459737> is not JSON serializable` 
Would really appreciate some help here .

Comment: Ok, I solved the above error by passing the final_task() a list of taskIds itself directly instead of passing it the list of task objects as is being done in the above code sample. Thanks anyway for the answer. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Celery has [plenty of tools](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html) for most of workflows you can imagine.

It seems you need to get use of [chord](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives). Here's a quote from docs:

> A chord is just like a group but with a callback. A chord consists of
>   a header group and a body, where the body is a task that should
>   execute after all of the tasks in the header are complete.

Comment: This is definitely right, however, there's a problem with it. I've updated my answer with the details.

Answer (score 3):

Taking a look at this snippet from your question, it looks like you are passing a `list` as the chord header, rather than a `group`:

```
from time import sleep
import random

tasks = []

for i in xrange(10):
    tasks.append(power.s((i, 2)))
    sleep(random.randint(10, 1000) / 1000.0) # sleep for 10-1000ms

callback = amass.s()

r = chord(tasks)(callback)
```

Converting the `list` to a `group` should result in the behaviour you're expecting:

```
...

callback = amass.s()

tasks = group(tasks)

r = chord(tasks)(callback)
```

Comment: upvoted! any ideas how this works if each group starts a new task and you want the chord to say wait for the subtasks of each group to complete

Comment: Sorry it's been a while since I looked into Celery in detail so I don't know the specifics of how 4.x works

Answer (score 0):

The answer that @alexander-afanasiev gave you is essentially right: use a chord.

Your code is OK, but `tasks.append(power.s((i, 2)))` is not actually executing the subtask, just adding [subtasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.subtask)  to a list. It's `chord(...)(...)` the one that send as many messages to the broker as subtasks you have defined in `tasks` list, plus one more message for the callback subtask. When you call `chord` it returns as soon as it can.

If you want to know when the chord has finished you can poll for completion like with a single task using `r.ready()` in your sample.

Comment: I want each subtask to execute as soon as it's posted, not when the chord is posted. Is that possible?

Comment: Well, just do a `power.delay(i, 2)` in the loop and poll all the intermediate results for completion before calling `amass(results)`.  But I don't really see the point. Using the chord will execute the `power.s` subtasks as soon as they are available as messages in the broker and `amass` after they finish. I think you should clarify what you want to achieve, because it seems your desire to execute the tasks asynchronously contradicts the usage you are proposing.

Comment: I came up with a solution above which demonstrates what I wanted to do.

Comment: I think you just have reimplemented the `chord` function.

Comment: Not at all: I think you don't understand what I'm asking. The chord function does not start executing tasks until it is called. However, in my code, tasks start executing immediately, and then a completion handler is also posted to the queue. In my use case, I'm not calling the actual chord function until some point in the future when I've started all necessary tasks for the job. Essentially, the chord function is lazy, only starting tasks when they've all been posted and the chord function is called. My implementation is eager, in that it starts all tasks as soon as possible.