# Need a celery task to start after all the other tasks have finished

Tags: python-2.7, celery

I am relatively new to Celery. I have a requirement that one of my celery tasks should start only after all the other tasks have finished. I did play around with it and also found some docs online, where it was indicated that I should be using `groups` and `chords` etc. which I could not really understand completely.

I also posted another question of SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976009/how-to-start-a-task-only-when-all-other-tasks-have-finished-in-celery?noredirect=1#comment80901257_46976009) but did not find any convincing answers so far.

Finally I came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308849/running-a-task-after-all-tasks-have-been-completed) and I could clearly (at least conceptually) understand what was going on in the accepted answer. However, when I tried replicating the exact same program at my end, it threw the below error :

`EncodeError: <AsyncResult: cf5875f1-7f72-449c-9808-07c9c9459737> is not JSON serializable`

I have posted the same in the comments as well in the above question, the question seems to be very old and hence I haven't received any traction on my comment so far.

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Have a look at [no-one answered my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers). Re-posting is not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308849/running-a-task-after-all-tasks-have-been-completed) actually helped me achieve what I wanted to. (Probably this was a hacky way of doing it, but it solved my problem). The answer however threw an error as :

`EncodeError: <AsyncResult: cf5875f1-7f72-449c-9808-07c9c9459737> is not JSON serializable`

Which I was able to solve as below (I have mentioned this change also in the comments on that answer)

So in the **Use Case** part in the answer :

```
tasks = []
for i in xrange(10):
    tasks.append(power.delay(i, 2))

amass.delay([], tasks)
```

as the second parameter to the `amass.delay()` we are passing a list of task objects. I just changed this to actually pass a list of task IDs instead. So the `amass()` now looks like :

```
tasks = []
for i in xrange(10):
    x = power.delay(i, 2)
    tasks.append(x.id)

amass.delay([], tasks)
```

and made the respective changes in the `amass()` as shown below
and it solved the error and did the job i was trying to achieve.

```
@celery.task()
def amass(results, tasks):
    completed_tasks = []
    for task_id in tasks:
        result = AsyncResult(task_id, app=celery)
        if result.ready():
            completed_tasks.append(task_id)
            #results.append(task.get()) did not need this so commented it out

    # remove completed tasks
    tasks = list(set(tasks) - set(completed_tasks))

    if len(tasks) > 0:
        # resend the task to execute at least 1 second from now
        amass.delay(results, tasks, countdown=1)
    else:
        # we done
        print results
```

Answer (score 0):

*If*

you already have a list of tasks which have to be executed one after another and want to combine the results you have to use [chords](http://ask.github.io/celery/userguide/tasksets.html#chords) only.

*else*

If you keep adding tasks to celery (not immediately) and you want them to be executed one by one, then just by setting up 1 worker with concurrency=1 you can achieve this, the tasks get executed one by serially only.

I also had the parallel execution issue befor, I had solved it by running one worker with concurrency=1 in the beginning, But later I used redis locking mechanism to achieve the workaround.